# Why is surjectivity "harder" than injectivity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, category-theory, soft-question

Injectivity and surjectivity are very intimately related, however, in any particular structure, one of them tends to be a much "harder" property - just looking at basic set theory, we have that a function is injective iff it has a left inverse, and surjective iff it has a right inverse. But immediately something crops up: the former is a harmless statement provable in ZF, but the latter is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Going on to basic algebra, we see that kernels  are totally related to the injectiveness of a function, and studying them tend to be much easier, while cokernels tend to bring in no new information (and at least, at the lower level, seem to be just a fancy but useless substitute for studying  surjectivity). We also see that theorems about surjectivity tend to be more important (off the top of my head, the isomorphism extension theorem in field theory). Surjectivity questions tend to have to be answered constructively, which in my experience, is generally hard.

That is not to say that the opposite isn't true - from memory, projective resolutions were significantly easier than injective ones.

My question is: is there a "deep" reason as to why one of the two tend to be much "harder" than the other?

Comment: Injective iff left inverse is actually not true; it doesn't hold for the function from the empty set to any inhabited (= non-empty) set.  Still, it's easier to characterize them in ZF.

Comment: This is an absolute shot in the dark, but I wonder if this is connected to the existence of [initial/terminal objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) in a category.  For instance, $\mathsf{Sets}$ has the empty set as an initial object, and its monomorphisms are "easy" to characterize.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: $\mathsf{Sets}$ also has terminal objects: the singleton is terminal (and unique up to bijection).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I feel silly for forgetting about that... so probably my guess is totally wrong

Comment: On the other hand, note that injectivity is characterized by a $\forall$ statement, whereas surjectivity is characterized by a $\forall\exists$; that’s already a significant difference. Caveat: kernels work for groups, rings, vector spaces, modules. But they don’t work, e.g., for semigroups.

Comment: Btw: for a completely symmetric/dual characterization of surjective and injective functions that holds in ZF, a function is injective iff it is left cancellable, and a function is surjective iff it is right cancellable.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin is there a difference between saying that $f$ is "right cancellable" and saying that $f$ "has a right inverse"? If not, then doesn't proving that surjectivity implies right cancellability require the axiom of choice?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:  "right cancellable" means that if $ac = bc$, then $a=b$.  If $c$ has a right inverse, it must be right cancellable, but the converse isn't true.  For example, in $\mathbb{Z}$, $a\cdot 3 = b\cdot 3$ implies $a=b$ even though $\frac{1}{3}\notin\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: An answer to my own question: right-cancelability is weaker. A proof is as follows: suppose that $f:X \to Y$ is surjective, and $g \neq h:Y \to Z$. There exists $y \in Y$ such that $g(y) \neq h(y)$.  By surjectivity, there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$.  We see that $g(f(x)) \neq g(h(x))$.  That is, $g \neq h \implies g \circ f \neq h \circ f$. Thus, $g \circ f = h \circ f \implies g = h$.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for that.  Nice example.

Comment: Similar to distinction of $\forall$ and $\forall \exists$ from @ArturoMagidin Comment: one can see that definition of injectivity only involves function composition, whereas surjectivity involves pull backs -  a relatively advanced concept than function composition. However, this doesn't really answer the "WHY" posed in the question. Perhaps, one could say that *Injectivity is defined on the domain* whereas *surjectivity is defined on the co-domain*. Not sure how this may help, but thought I should write as it may help.

Comment: Another distinction is that surjectivity only makes sense when you think of functions as triples (domain, codomain, set of pairs), whereas injectivity also makes sense when you think of functions as simply sets of ordered pairs satisfying $(a,b),(a,b’)\in f\implies b=b’$, making “injectivity” a slightly more “primitive” notion than surjectivity, despite the general duality.

Comment: To me it feels like the difference is injectivity (mono-ness) can be checked by taking a pullback, surjectivity (epic-ness) can be checked by taking a pushout, and pullbacks are easy to understand in $\mathbf{Set}$ or nice algebraic categories more generally, since they are subobjects of the product defined by a single equation, whereas pushouts are hard to understand, since they are quotients of the coproduct by a relation. The relation has a simple generating set, but it can be very hard to understand the generated relation.

Comment: In my feeling, injectivity is more a local phenomenon while surjectivity is global.

Comment: Functions are special types of relations: those that are right-unique and left-total. Those properties are of course not symmetric between left and right. I would bet that that is the root cause of the issue. Unfortunately, if one tries to port any of these structures to more general relations, it has the feeling of venturing out into the untamable wilderness.

Comment: @EricAuld This is the real answer to the question posed. It should be posted as an answer, with the terms explained.

Answer (score 7):

I’d try to explain this as follows: we are in the habit of understanding a set $S$ in terms of the maps from a singleton $*$ to $S$. This breaks the symmetry dramatically between “epimorphism” and “monomorphism,” the left- and right-cancellations conditions discussed in the comments.

Indeed, if you know $f:S\to T$ is a monomorphism, then you know immediately from the definition that $f$ does not identify any two distinct points $x,y:*\to S$. But if you know $f$ is an epimorphism, it’s much less obvious what this means in terms of maps from the point into $S$ and $T$. You have to know a lot more about the structure of sets to say that, if there were any point of $T$ not in the image of $f$, then one could construct two unequal maps out of $T$ equalized by $f$. And these maps out of $T$ wouldn’t most naturally be into any nice fixed set like $*$! At best, you could use maps $T\to \{0,1\}$.

In fact, if you know enough about $\{0,1\}$, you know you can characterize the epis as precisely the maps $f$ which induce a mono on powersets, $f^*:\{0,1\}^T\to \{0,1\}^S$. So one might measure the difference in difficulty of injective versus surjective maps by considering how much more complex the powerset is than the mere set. For instance, the powerset construction isn’t even available in most other categories, though $\mathbb k$ serves the same role among finite dimensional vector spaces.